# Save TensorFlow state (weights) while running

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've got a python program that is running fitting over a model.
I didn't implements a saver so i'm wondering if there's a method to recover the weights directly from memory (maybe from a temp file?) while the fitting is running

Comment: To clarify, you did not code in checkpoints where the weights were saved to disk, and now that the model is currently fitting, you'll like to be able to attempt to save the weights from the currently fitting model? Or did the model complete fitting without saving weights, and you want to recover those weights?

Comment: The model is still running (and fitting)

Comment: If the model is currently running and you did not put in any checkpoints for saving to file, there is likely no good way to obtain the weights. They could be anywhere in memory, and could be changing while you're trying to extract them, resulting in inconsistent data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be possible using the command, `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)`.

Code for extracting/recovering weights of a model without Saving the Model is shown below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, 5], name="Input")
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, 1], name="Output")

X = np.random.randint(1,10,[10,5])
Y = np.random.randint(0,2,[10,1])

with tf.variable_scope("LogReg"):
    pred = tf.layers.dense(X_, 1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, name = 'fc1')
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=Y_, predictions=pred)
    training_ops = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    all_vars= tf.global_variables()
    def get_var(name):
        for i in range(len(all_vars)):
            if all_vars[i].name.startswith(name):
                return all_vars[i]
        return None

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())    
    for i in range(200):
        sess.run([training_ops], feed_dict={X_: X,Y_: Y})
        Weight_Vars = sess.run([tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)], feed_dict={X_: X,Y_: Y})
        print(Weight_Vars)
```